# Stop refresh from uitableview when scrolling

Tags: ios, uitableview, swift3

This is the first state when i enter the chat screen first time:
[First state](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8kYQQ.jpg)

And this is the second state when i start scrolling UITableView up to down or down to up
[Second state](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XV4FZ.jpg)

The main problem is the table cells are changing when i scroll up and down so, i already have my datasource in an array, 
the cells must draw a chat bubble depending on the type of message received from me or another person this causes the chat bubble to pull to the left or right of the cell but the scroll refreshing makes to redraw the chat bubble into cell

I don't know why, help please!

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming you have one `cellForRow` method that is dequeuing `reusable` cells for all the rows in your table. If so, I would recommend the following approach.

- Dequeue cell
- **Reset cell's property (this goes for all properties like color, alignment, etc.)**
- Define cell's attribute based on different conditions

Comment: I fixed the redraw problem removing the subviews from the view that contains the bubble, i can call this as like you say "reset properties". Thank you very much @Malik